# How do I use d3.domain to get d3.min and d3.max from multiple columns in a JSON file?

Tags: html, json, d3.js, visualization

This is a JSON file that I am using and I would like to use ysec.domain([d3.min(data, function (d) { return (the lowest value from the three columns "male","female" and "both")}), d3.max(data, function (d) { return (the highest value from the three columns "male","female" and "both")}) ]); 
Is there anyway for me to set the min value to be the lowest value from the three columns: "male","female" and "both" and this applies to the max value too?

```
[{"year":"1960","male":"61.7","female":"65.7","both":"63.7","rankmale":"47","rankfemale":"50","rankall":"45"},
{"year":"1970","male":"65.4","female":"70.2","both":"67.7","rankmale":"45","rankfemale":"45","rankall":"44"},
{"year":"1980","male":"68.9","female":"74.2","both":"71.5","rankmale":"33","rankfemale":"36","rankall":"29"},
{"year":"1990","male":"71.9","female":"76.9","both":"74.3","rankmale":"28","rankfemale":"30","rankall":"30"},
{"year":"2000","male":"76.1","female":"80.1","both":"78.1","rankmale":"11","rankfemale":"24","rankall":"15"},
{"year":"2011","male":"80.1","female":"84.6","both":"82.3","rankmale":"6","rankfemale":"8","rankall":"5"}]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your case, you don't really need to consider `both` column since it's the average of `male` and `female` column. The simplest way that I can think of to solve your problem is something like this

```
var max = d3.max(data, function(d){
    return (d.male < d.female) ? d.female : d.male;
});

var min = d3.min(data, function(d){
    return (d.male < d.female) ? d.male : d.female;
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Fortunately you don't need both in this scenario, but if you did, you could use the `Math.max()` and `Math.min()` function to take the max or min value of multiple values. So your max and min values might look like:

```
var max = d3.max(data, function(d){
    Math.max(d.male, d.female, d.both);
});
var max = d3.min(data, function(d){
    Math.min(d.male, d.female, d.both);
});
```

The `Math.max()` and `Math.min()` functions work with however many columns you want to work with.