# Get max value from array with multiple columns

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to get the max value from an array with multiple columns using the second answer from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25161867/how-do-i-use-d3-domain-to-get-d3-min-and-d3-max-from-multiple-columns-in-a-json) but one of my columns name have an space in it I tired to set a variable with that column name but didn't work.

my data looks like this:

```
data=[
 {group: "A", Moderada: 3, Baja: 27, Alta: 1, Muy Alta: 0}
 {group: "B", Moderada: 8, Baja: 20, Alta: 5, Muy Alta: 5}
 {group: "C", Moderada: 6, Baja: 18, Alta: 7, Muy Alta: 6}
 {group: "D", Moderada: 1, Baja: 23, Alta: 2, Muy Alta: 9}
]
```

and the code is:

```
const MuyAlta="Muy Alta"

max= d3.max(data, function(d){
    return (Math.max(d.Baja, d.Moderada, d.Alta, d.MuyAlta))});

console.log(max);
```

the console.log() should return `27`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe like This:

```js
data=[
 {group: "A", Moderada: 3, Baja: 27, Alta: 1, 'Muy Alta': 0},
 {group: "B", Moderada: 8, Baja: 20, Alta: 5, 'Muy Alta': 5},
 {group: "C", Moderada: 6, Baja: 18, Alta: 7, 'Muy Alta': 6},
 {group: "D", Moderada: 1, Baja: 23, Alta: 2, 'Muy Alta': 9},
];

function my_max(_data){
 var out = 0;
 for(var key in _data){
   out = Math.max(out, _data[key].Baja, _data[key].Moderada, _data[key].Alta, _data[key]['Muy Alta']);
 }
 return out;
}

console.log(my_max(data));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use d["Muy Alta"]

```
max = d3.max(data, function(d){
    return (Math.max(d.Baja, d.Moderada, d.Alta, d["Muy Alta"]))});

console.log(max);
```